# Spring Security Tables

Tags: spring, spring-security

In the spring security documentation , there are five tables to be created .

1.users
2.authorities ( map users to authorities ) 
3.groups
4.groups_authorities ( map groups to authorities )
5.group_members  ( map users to groups )

Why do we need to map both users and authorities to groups ? If we map either authroities or users to groups , cant we derive the other relationship ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to this approach, every user can have some extra authority - authority not granted by being in any of his/her groups.

For instance:

- `user1` is in groups `admins`, `plain_users`
- `admins` group has authority `ROLE_ADMIN`
- `plain_users` group has authority `ROLE_USER`
- `user1` has some extra authority `ROLE_SUPER_USER`

After being successfully authenticated his/her `List<GrantedAuthority>` contains `ROLE_ADMIN`, `ROLE_USER` and ... that extra `ROLE_SUPER_USER` authority.

Comment: The same objective can be achieved by defining three groups  
1.admins with **ROLE_ADMIN**
2.plain_users with **ROLE_USER**
3.super_users with **ROLE_SUPER_USER**.
_user1_ can be added as a member to all these three groups.

Comment: You're right. So Spring Security is flexible enough to accept many different domain models.